# Merge two Rails models

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a friendship table,

```
create_table "friendships", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer  "user_id"
  t.integer  "friend_id"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  t.string   "name"
end
```

When a user adds a friend the friendship model creates a new record with a unique id a `user_id` a `friend_id` and a `name` value.

In my angular app I have a template that repeats each `friendship in friendships`.

This is the json result when a friend has been added,

```
[{"id":17,"friend_id":3,"name":"Kees Keesen"}]
```

The id is the id of the friendship and the `friend_id` is the actual user id of the friend.

So what I am doing now is duplicating my data. I have a user model with the names, emails etc. But when I add a friend I have to add a name value (and more) to the friendship record.

This is the json result from users.json,

```
{"id":3,"email":"kees@kees.nl","name":"Kees Keesen"}
```

So is it possible to keep the friendship unqique id (which I need to remove the friendship record), but make a link to the user model so I don't have to duplicate my data?

*** update ***

Here's my friendship controller,

```
def index
  friends = current_user.friendships.as_json
  # friends = current_user.friends.as_json(:only => [:name, :email, :id])
  render :json => friends
end
```

I've added this to my user model,

```
has_many :friendships
has_many :friends, :through => :friendships
has_many :inverse_friendships, :class_name => "Friendship", :foreign_key => "friend_id"
has_many :inverse_friends, :through => :inverse_friendships, :source => :user
```

And this to my friendship model,

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :friend, :class_name => "User"
```

I've removed the name column from the friendship table, the json output for friendship is now,

```
[{"id":2,"user_id":1,"friend_id":1,"created_at":"2015-12-29T19:24:28.788Z","updated_at":"2015-12-29T19:24:28.788Z"}]
```

Answer (score 1):

The way to happiness here is with a self-referential association.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base    
  has_many :friendships
  has_many :friends, :through => :friendships
  has_many :inverse_friendships, :class_name => "Friendship", :foreign_key => "friend_id"
  has_many :inverse_friends, :through => :inverse_friendships, :source => :user
end

class Friendship < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :friend, class_name: "User"
end
```

With this solution, you'll get a unique id for data structure constraints, a `user_id` for your user, and a `friend_id` for the reciprocal aspect of the friendship, both of which point to the `User` model to avoid duplication. This is a pretty common way to do things.

A note here: `inverse_friendships` are used to query who a particular user has been added by, instead of who they've personally added.

**UPDATE**

In order to access `User` information via a `Friendship`, it's possible to delegate the attribute calls:

```
class Friendship < ActiveRecord::Base
  ... snip ...

  delegate :name, :email, to: :friend
end
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for the input. I might be applying the code wrong, but there seems to be no change. What would you expect the json to be? Also if I comment out the code in the `friendship` model the json still gets rendered the same, in other words the friendship model doesn't seem to be doing anything. Ah I see you got the code from the Railscast. That was my guide as well.

Comment: If your JSON isn't changing at all, you should restart everything. That's very different code ;) Easiest thing would be to check and make sure your JSON representation doesn't have a name field in it.

Comment: Hm. I've closed down my rails server. Removed the name column from the friendship table, resetted my database and reseeded but still the json output isn't changed. I've updated my question to reflect the changes. Maybe you can spot something I'm doing wrong? Perhaps in the controller.

Comment: What's wrong with that JSON output? You're no longer duplicating any data, as per that new JSON request object.

Comment: I expect/want the JSON output to be something like this `[{"id":2,"user_id":1,""friend_id":3,"name":"Kees Keesen""}]
`

`id: 2` is the relationship id. `friend_id 3` is the id of the User kees and `name: Kees Keesen` is the name of the user. 

With the current json output I can only display the relationship id through a `ng-repeat => friendship in friendships` and I want to show the name, email etc. as well.

Comment: Thanks again, but it seems that the `friendship` model doesn't do anything. If I empty it the json output is the same. I think the problem is that `friend` isn't being used anywhere.

Comment: According to your JSON object up above, you're using the same object for both the user and the "friend". Try switching that up to include two separate user objects. If that doesn't change anything, feel free to invite me to chat further so we can keep comments short.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99289/discussion-between-peter-boomsma-and-collin-graves).

Answer (score 0):

In the angular side of things, you should make a method to get user by id, which accesses a cache behind the scenes. Then when you get a friendship, replace the ids with the user objects they represent, using this method. If the user has already been seen, then you won't need to request it again from the server. JSON format has the disadvantage of not being able to represent links, so we tend to use IDs instead, and just turn them into links once we get the object.